# CSRF Token in Phonegap using AJAX

Tags: ajax, django, cordova, csrf

I'm developing an app with `Phonegap` that uses Django back-end. The back-end uses `csrf`, so I need my `Phonegap` app to use `csrf` so it can work with `Django`.

I've read that you can use `csrf` via Ajax, but I haven't been able to make it work.

Could you please tell me with an example how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just catch csrf_token in your html page in script tag at a time of document ready by

> var csrf = {{ csrf_token }}

and then via ajax pass parameter like in your js file

> $.ajax({
>
> ```
>      csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf;
>      ..//
> ```
>
> });

Comment: And how can I blend this with a POST form? I'm really really new to html and javascript programming (and due to lack of personal it has to be me who does this)

Comment: @Sascuash , on authentication , get csrf token from response . use it for subsequent request.

Comment: @zigs I am not sure about `phonegap` . Is phonegap uses html as template ??

Comment: Well, phonegap uses Html, CSS and Javascript, but when using {{ csrf_token }} it shows the text "{{ csrf_token }}", so I guess it somehow works in a different way that browsers

Comment: This worked, but I had to make a call asking for a new csrf in first place as @PriyankPatel said, then store it and send it later.

Answer (score 3):

Extending @Zigs Answer .

You can generate csrf token at server(Django) side using :

```
from django.middleware.csrf import _get_new_csrf_key as get_new_csrf_key
response.set_cookie("csrftoken", get_new_csrf_key())
```

Use this csrf token for subsequent POST (ajax) request.