# csrf protection on mobile devices ( running in cordova)

Tags: javascript, android, django, cordova, csrf

I want to deploy my mobile app, but before that I want to settle the csrf protection buisness.

My app is a Cordiva app, and the server is a Django server. My app communicates with the server only with ajax. No static files are ever served.

Right now, I simply make a GET request to the browser to get the csrf-string.

Is that a normal way to do this?

On StackOverflow, there's a post: [CSRF Token in Phonegap using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294866/csrf-token-in-phonegap-using-ajax) that shows how to set the cookie but it doesnt apply to me as my static pages arent served by the browser. They're on the mobile phone's memory.

On wikipedia, there's an example using CORS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing. They specifically say that the browser will send `Origin: http://www.example-mysite.com` to the server. But what will the mobile device send? It has no domain-name.

So again, how can I use csrf_protection on the phone? Can I simply make a method on my server that will send a csrf-string to anyone that asks for it? I'm not sure that that's the way I should do it.

Please, if you've been on this road before, let me know what are the typical solutions?

Thanks in advance for your kind help and concern.

Jenia.

Comment: how would anyone penetrate your app that would necessitate even bothering with csrf? it's an over-rated problem on desktop webpages, where there are actual vectors like comments, but an app shouldn't have such issues.

Comment: okay. but how will the server know if the request is comming from the mobile app or from a desktop? this app can run on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup your sever to only accept request with a specific Request Header.

Example : APPLICATION-ID : 5sdc421cs624d

```
// Request with custom header
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo/bar',
    headers: { 'APPLICATION-ID': '5sdc421cs624d' }
});
```

Then you will need to have this header to request the csrf-string.

Comment: thank a lot thom-x. can i send this as GET or it must be a POST?

Comment: You can send it as GET or POST.

Comment: I'm not totally sure how this would prevent CSRF. An attacker can also set the same setting on their site where the form is submitted.